# Java: Constructing a Map from a single expression?

Tags: java, dictionary, construct

I wonder why there's no way to construct a map with values in a single expression. Or is it? I'd expect

```
new HashMap().add(key, value).add(key, value)...;
```

I can't find anything like that even in Commons Collections.

Did I miss some way in JDK or Commons?

Comment: Guava has that, see my answer

Comment: If you want a JDK only solution, you could write a simple class to do that, but it would be very limited.

Comment: @Djon it is actualy pretty easy to implement a builder, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava has that with its [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
final Map<Foo, Bar> map = ImmutableMap.of(foo1, bar1, foo2, bar2, etc, etc);
```

Bonus: `ImmutableMap`'s name is not a lie ;)

Note that there are 5 versions of the `.of()` method, so up to 5 key/value pairs. A more generic way is to use a builder:

```
final Map<Foo, Bar> map = ImmutableMap.<Foo, Bar>builder()
    .put(foo1, bar1)
    .put(foo2, bar2)
    .put(foo3, bar3)
    .put(etc, etc)
    .build();
```

Note, however: this map **does not** accept null keys or values.

Alternatively, here is a poor man's version of `ImmutableMap`. It uses a classical builder pattern. Note that it does not check for nulls:

```
public final class MapBuilder<K, V>
{
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public MapBuilder<K, V> put(final K key, final V value)
    {
        map.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public Map<K, V> build()
    {
        // Return a mutable copy, so that the builder can be reused
        return new HashMap<K, V>(map);
    }

    public Map<K, V> immutable()
    {
        // Return a copy wrapped into Collections.unmodifiableMap()
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(build());
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
final Map<K, V> map = new MapBuilder<K, V>().put(...).put(...).immutable();
```

Comment: By pure habit. I make variables final where they can be, classes final when they are not meant to be inherited.

Comment: I put `const` whenever I can in C++, but I never thought of it in Java, strange world.

Comment: @Djon it also has nice side effects, such as allowing the use of a method parameter in an inner class which you return; if the method parameter were not final, this could not be possible. But in the end, it is all about coding style/habits/policy. I am final-happy ;)

Comment: Ad `final`: Restricting API has a nice result of having restricted API :) One can easily relax the API (e.g. remove `final`), but the other way is quite painful to the API consumers.

Comment: @OndraŽižka well, if you design a class so as not to allow it to be extended, `final` is there for you ;)

Comment: Most classes shouldn't be extended, in an API, unless documented and the class is ready for it. And users can always suggest lifting off the constraint. m2c, YMMV.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I agree... But better safe than sorry ;) m2c2, YMMV

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
{{
     put("One", 1);
     put("Two", 2);
     put("Three", 3);
}};
```

Comment: The above code makes use of `block initialization`. To make it clear, it creates an anonymous class whose only content is a block that will call several `put`

Comment: This can cause subtle problems due to the implicit reference to the outer class https://blog.p-y.wtf/avoid-java-double-brace-initialization

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Commons Collections or in the JDK. But you could alternatively use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and the following code:

```
Map<String, String> mapInstance = ImmutableMap.<String, String> builder().put("key1", "value1").put("key2", "value2").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

- If your your keys and vales are of the same type then having such method:

  ```
  <K> Map<K, K> init(Map<K, K> map, K... args) {
      K k = null;
      for(K arg : args) {
          if(k != null) {
              map.put(k, arg);
              k = null;
          } else {
              k = arg;
          }
      }
      return map;
  }
  ```

  You can initialize your map with:

  ```
  init(new HashMap<String, String>(), "k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
  ```
- If your your keys and vales are of a different type then having such method:

  ```
  <K, V> Map<K, V> init(Map<K, V> map, List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
      for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
          map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
      }
      return map;
  }
  ```

  You can initialize your map with:

  ```
  init(new HashMap<String, Integer>(), 
       Arrays.asList("k1", "k2"), 
       Arrays.asList(1, 2));
  ```